# Create cookies on Droid Turbo local drive using Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android

Developing XHTML based product for Droid Turbo. Chrome will not permit javascript from file:/// to create cookies for security reasons. If Chrome is started with "--enable-file-cookies" then cookies can be created but how can Chrome startup be customized on Droid Turbo? Instead of referencing file:/// is it possible to access the same files via http://127.0.0.1, which apparently will not trigger the Chrome cookie problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered today that Chrome also prohibits geo-location for file:/// based web pages. Enough! Installed Mozilla Firefox on Droid Turbo. End of problem.